# How to follow a trajectory with rigify?

Tags: armature, rigify, path

I am using rigify addon to animate my character.
What would be the best way to make him follow a trajectory ?
1/ parenting armature object to a path constraint ?
2/ parenting the root bone of the armature only to the path in pose mode ?
3/ parenting all the bones in pose mode to the path constraint ?

Or another solution might be to not use a path, but to make an action in dope sheet to define the trajectory of the character.
Because if I understand well, it is not necessary to create an action for trajectory when using a path. Right?

So what would be the best way to make my character following a trajectory for you?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You should never transform the armature object. In complex rigs it can cause problems. That's what the Root bone is for - to position the character in scene. So your 2/ solution is the right one.

Comment: Thank you that is what I tried. But the problem is that when I move my character through its armature (root bone) to place it over the beginning of the path, and I set the path constraint to the root bone, the character "jump", indeed it jumps far from the  path

Comment: Make sure your armature object is in the center of the scene and that you have no pose transform on the Root bone - it is not moved (ALT+G, ALT+R, ALT+S), select the path, *shift-select* the Root bone in pose mode, add constraint with CTRL+SHIFT+C > Follow Path. Animate the *Evaluation Time* property of the path under *Path Animation*. Should work.

Comment: Ok I see. But the thing is that the path wont be at the center of the scene (it will be a path in a particular place of landscape map). So I still need to have the armature object right at the center of the seen even if the path is at another place? If so, how can I make my character joining differents paths? I mean, for example, during 200 frames it will follow the first path, and then at this new place, it will follow the second path?

Comment: Yes, even if the path is at some location, the armature object has to be in scene center. If you need to follow one path animation with another, you need to animate the influences of the follow_path constraints: the first will go from 100 to 0 and the other vice-versa.

Comment: Ok cool that is interesting. I am asking because I want my character do a specific action between the 2 paths (take an object). So I am trying to see how I can do this. The idea is to keep the position where the character will be when finishing the first path, then, at this location, create the action to take the object and finally start the second path? Is it the way you would do?